# C# Console App print to network printer

Tags: c#, printing, console-application

Working on a console app that is sending a print job to a network printer. When the console app is running on my local machine, the printer prints out the document.  When we move the console app to the virtual machine and run it there, the console app logs that it printed the document successfully but nothing is printed.  The printer is installed on the VM and I am able to print out a document from Notepad.  Wben watching the print queue on the vm it shows the job spooling but soon after it disappears.  This is the code we have:

```
 public void Print(PrintRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Preparing to print on {request.FullPrinterName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Document Name: {request.DocumentName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Document Length: {request.DocumentContent.Length}");

        var srv = new PrintServer($@"\\{ request.HostName}");
        var printQueue = srv.GetPrintQueue(request.PrinterName);
        var fileContent = request.DocumentContent;

        Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to print {request.FullPrinterName}");

        using (var job = printQueue.AddJob($"Print {request.DocumentName}"))
        {
            using (var stream = job.JobStream)
            {                    
                stream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully printed {request.DocumentName}");
        }
    }
```

My local machine is running Windows 7 and the virtual machine is running Windows server 2012.  Any idea on why it will print when the console app is running locally versus when it is running on the vm.

Comment: Is `fileContent` definitely being populated correctly on the VM? It could be that, if it's empty, it may be successfully printing a file with no contents, hence seeing it appear in the queue and then disappear.

Comment: I'll add some logging in to see what the byte[] length is when I get a chance.  I'm guessing it is since it does when running locally, but I'll double check.  Thanks for the quick response.